# How could I align the statements under a same theorem

Tags: align

I have a theorem that contains multiple statements, but the statement is not align in a right way as picture showing
[image]

So, how could I improve this problem?

```
\begin{theorem}

If A is an n × n symmetric matrix, then the following statements hold：

1.A has exactly n real eigenvalues counting for multiplicity.\\

2.The eigenvector corresponding to distinct eigen value are orthogonal.\\

3.A is orthogonal diagonalizable.\\
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that usually it is best to provide a minimal document containing `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` so that those wanting to help you don't have to add that themselves. Also, please note that ending a line with `\\ ` outside of `tabular` and friends, is usually the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

Since it is likely that you have several theorems like that, it is sensible to define a suitable environment for them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{statements}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{\arabic*.},ref=\arabic*,nosep]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{Symmetric matrices}

\begin{theorem}
If $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, then the following statements hold:
\begin{statements}
\item $A$ has exactly $n$ real eigenvalues counting for multiplicity;

\item eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal;

\item $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable.
\end{statements}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This way, if you change your mind about the typesetting, you can just act in a single place, rather than chasing through your document. For instance, changing `nosep` into `noitemsep` would produce

[image]

whereas removing `nosep` altogether would produce

[image]

Some stylistic remarks.

1. The leading item numbers should be upright rather than italic.
2. Punctuation should be consistent. If you end the preamble with a colon, then the items should be separated by a semicolon or a comma. Capitalizing the first word in an item is optional, but you must be consistent across the whole document.
3. Even if “A” is a single letter, you *must* use `$A$` or `\(A\)` because it is a math formula nonetheless.
4. If you write “eigenvector”, be consistent and also write “eigenvalue”.
5. “The eigenvector” is (mathematically) wrong: a matrix always has infinitely many eigenvectors relative to a given eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4):

You should use an `enumerate` environment nested inside your `theorem`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  If $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, then the following statements hold:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $A$ has exactly $n$ real eigenvalues counting for multiplicity.
    \item The eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.
    \item $A$ is orthogonal diagonalizable.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
\begin{theorem}

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, then the following statements hold：
\begin{enumerate}
\item $A$ has exactly n real eigenvalues counting for multiplicity.
\item The eigenvector corresponding to distinct eigen value are orthogonal.
\item $A$ is orthogonal diagonalizable.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```